# Fastest method to scrape new webpage content

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

For a given webpage with a list of news articles, I would like to scrape the content of a newly published article as quickly as possible as time is critical for this task.

So far I used `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` libraries to scrape the content from a news webpage. This makes it possible to scrape a new news article in about one to two seconds. In forums, I often found that it just takes a certain time to do a webpage request and this is a bottleneck that can't be much improved. But maybe someone has a good idea...

A generic sample code of how I scrape new news articles is shown below:

```
page = requests.get(webpage)
old_content = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser") # The latest article was scraped to have a comparison variable

while new_content == content:
     page = requests.get(webpage)
     new_content = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

# Code that uses new_content, if new_content =! old_content
```

Does anyone have an idea how new webpage content could be scraped much faster? Ideally, this would take much less than one second.

Comment: Could it be an internet bottleneck, and not a code bottleneck? If it is an internet bottleneck, there's not much you can do besides using Ethernet or optimizing your code, by requesting less of the webpage or something.

Comment: The dynamic content must be loaded from somewhere. Figure out where that is and have your script retrieve it directly rather than scraping it from the page. Either way, keep in mind that sites generally don't like it when you abuse them by rapidly, repeatedly requesting content.

Answer (score 0):

You said you are looking for the newly published articles, I think there's no media site that publishes an article every minute. So you can cache the result and update it maybe every one hour.

So assuming you are scraping that content at the run time of a client-server request, there will be one request that would take 1-2 seconds every one hour, otherwise, you get the data from the cache.

You can make it more optimized if you used a scheduled job in the background or maybe a cron job that runs a script every 1 hour and stores the result in a database or something that you can fetch data from so quickly.